# Create a file at time 't' after PBS job execution begins

Tags: job-control, batch-jobs, torque

I submit a PBS job for `02:00:00 hours`. I need to create a file in the PBS working directory at a specified time ***t*** `(say 01:30:00 hours)` after the job has begun to ensure that the job terminates smoothly for any subsequent restart. For example something as follows

```
echo "LABORT" > file1.txt
```

I do not want to rely on PBS for the file creation through chaining jobs, since  I want to create it exactly at the specified time. Is there a clean and automated way to achieve this while running many such jobs?

EDIT 1:
I believe crontab can perform the task, but how to perform the following

- monitor the jobs under a given username,
- get the job start time and working directory
- Add the time t to start time and Pass the modified
- time and working directory to crontab

Comment: You probably want to look at PBS "hooks" which are python scripts run by PBS on events you specify.